# Select latest and 2nd latest date rows per user

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following query to select rows where the `LAST_UPDATE_DATE` field is getting records that have a date value greater than or equal to the last 7 days, which works great.

```
   SELECT 'NEW ROW' AS 'ROW_TYPE', A.EMPLID, B.FIRST_NAME, B.LAST_NAME,
    A.BANK_CD, A.ACCOUNT_NUM, ACCOUNT_TYPE, PRIORITY, A.LAST_UPDATE_DATE
   FROM PS_DIRECT_DEPOSIT D
    INNER JOIN PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB A ON A.EMPLID = D.EMPLID AND A.EFFDT = D.EFFDT
    INNER JOIN PS_EMPLOYEES B ON B.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
   WHERE 
    B.EMPL_STATUS NOT IN ('T','R','D')
    AND ((A.DEPOSIT_TYPE = 'P' AND A.AMOUNT_PCT = 100)
          OR A.PRIORITY = 999
          OR A.DEPOSIT_TYPE = 'B')
    AND A.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(A1.EFFDT)
                   FROM PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB A1
                   WHERE A1.EMPLID = A.EMPLID
                    AND A1.EFFDT <= GETDATE())
    AND D.EFF_STATUS = 'A'
    AND D.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(D1.EFFDT)
                   FROM PS_DIRECT_DEPOSIT D1
                   WHERE D1.EMPLID = D.EMPLID
                    AND D1.EFFDT <= GETDATE())
    AND A.LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= GETDATE() - 7
```

What I would like to add onto this is to also add the previous (2nd MAX) row per EMPLID, so that I can output the 'old' row (that was prior to the last update the latest row meeting above criteria), along with the new row that I already am outputting in the query.

```
ROW_TYPE      EMPLID    FIRST_NAME   LAST_NAME      BANK_CD     ACCOUNT_NUM     ACCOUNT_TYPE    PRIORITY    LAST_UPDATE_DATE
NEW ROW       12345     JOHN         SMITH          123548999   45234879        C               999         2019-03-06 00:00:00.000
OLD ROW       12345     JOHN         SMITH          214080046   92178616        C               999         2018-10-24 00:00:00.000
NEW ROW       56399     CHARLES      MASTER         785816167   84314314        C               999         2019-03-07 00:00:00.000   
OLD ROW       56399     CHARLES      MASTER         345761227   547352          C               999         2017-05-16 00:00:00.000
```

So the `EMPLID` would be ordered by NEW ROW, followed by OLD ROW as shown above. In this example the 'NEW ROW' is getting the record that is within the past 7 days, as indicated by the `LAST_UPDATE_DATE`.

I would like to get feedback on how to modify the query so I can also get the 'old' row (which is the max row that is less than the 'NEW' row retrieved above).

Comment: Any ideas on accomplishing this?

Comment: Your query isn't doing what you're saying it's doing. It's pulling all records that were updated in the last 7 days, then embellishing those records with with additional data from other tables. If any records on `PS_DIRECT_DEPOSIT` have multiple updates in a week, you'll get them all, and the hard coded line in your query will label them all `NEW ROW`. So, are you looking for the two most recent updates by `EMPLID`? Or the previous update by an `EMPLID` for any employee who happened to have an update in the last week? Very different questions.

Comment: As an aside, you should [always use meaningful table aliases](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Comment: I'm looking for the the MAX LAST_UPDATE_DATE that is within the last 7 days, and for records where that is true I also want to display the 2nd newest (after the MAX row) row which would show what the previous values were for that record. Hope that makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was a slow day for crime in Gotham, so I gave this a whirl. Might work.

This is unlikely to work right out of the box, though, but it should get you started.

Your `LAST_UPDATE_DATE` column is on the table `PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB`, so we'll start there. First, you want to identify all of the records that were updated in the last 7 days because those are the only ones you're interested in. Throughout this, I'm assuming, and I'm probably wrong, that the natural key for the table consists of `EMPLID`, `BANK_CD`, and `ACCOUNT_NUM`. You'll want to sub in the actual natural key for those columns in a few places. That said, the date limiter looks something like this:

```
  SELECT
    EMPLID
   ,BANK_CD
   ,ACCOUNT_NUM
  FROM
    PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB AS limit
  WHERE
    limit.LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
    AND 
    limit.LAST_UPDATE_DATE <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Now we'll use that as a correlated sub-query in a `WHERE EXISTS` clause that we'll correlate back to the base table to limit ourselves to records with natural key values that were updated in the last week. I altered the `SELECT` list to just `SELECT 1`, which is typical verbiage for a correlated sub, since it stops looking for a match when it finds one (1), and doesn't actually return any values at all.

Additionally, since we're filtering this record set anyway, I moved all the other `WHERE` clause filters for this table into this (soon to be) sub-query.

Finally, in the `SELECT` portion, I added a `DENSE_RANK` to force order the records. We' use the `DENSE_RANK` value later to filter off only the first (*N*) records of interest.

So that leaves us with this:

```
SELECT
  EMPLID
 ,BANK_CD
 ,ACCOUNT_NUM
 --,ACCOUNT_TYPE --Might belong here. Can't tell without table alias in original SELECT
 ,PRIORITY
 ,EFFDT
 ,LAST_UPDATE_DATE
 ,DEPOSIT_TYPE
 ,AMOUNT_PCT
 ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY --Add actual natural key columns here...
                       EMPLID
                     ORDER BY
                       LAST_UPDATE_DATE DESC
                    ) AS RowNum
FROM
  PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB AS sdist
WHERE
  EXISTS
    (
      -- Get the set of records that were last updated in the last 7 days.
      -- Correlate to the outer query so it only returns records related to this subset.
      -- This uses a correlated subquery. A JOIN will work, too. Try both, pick the faster one.
      -- Something like this, using the actual natural key columns in the WHERE
      SELECT
        1
      FROM
        PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB AS limit
      WHERE
        --The first two define the date range.
        limit.LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
        AND limit.LAST_UPDATE_DATE <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
        AND
        --And these are the correlations to the outer query.
        limit.EMPLID = sdist.EMPLID
        AND limit.BANK_CD = sdist.BANK_CD
        AND limit.ACCOUNT_NUM = sdist.ACCOUNT_NUM
    )
  AND
  (
    dist.DEPOSIT_TYPE = 'P'
    AND dist.AMOUNT_PCT = 100
  )
  OR dist.PRIORITY = 999
  OR dist.DEPOSIT_TYPE = 'B'
```

Replace the original `INNER JOIN` to `PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB` with that query. In the `SELECT` list, the first hard-coded value is now dependent on the `RowNum` value, so that's a `CASE` expression now. In the `WHERE` clause, the dates are all driven by the subquery, so they're gone, several were folded into the subquery, and we're adding `WHERE dist.RowNum <= 2` to bring back the top 2 records.

(I also replaced all the table aliases so I could keep track of what I was looking at.)

```
SELECT
  CASE dist.RowNum
    WHEN 1 THEN 'NEW ROW'
    ELSE 'OLD ROW' 
  END AS ROW_TYPE
 ,dist.EMPLID
 ,emp.FIRST_NAME
 ,emp.LAST_NAME
 ,dist.BANK_CD
 ,dist.ACCOUNT_NUM
 ,ACCOUNT_TYPE
 ,dist.PRIORITY
 ,dist.LAST_UPDATE_DATE
FROM
  PS_DIRECT_DEPOSIT AS dd
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      EMPLID
     ,BANK_CD
     ,ACCOUNT_NUM
     --,ACCOUNT_TYPE --Might belong here. Can't tell without table alias in original SELECT
     ,PRIORITY
     ,EFFDT
     ,LAST_UPDATE_DATE
     ,DEPOSIT_TYPE
     ,AMOUNT_PCT
     ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY --Add actual natural key columns here...
                           EMPLID
                         ORDER BY
                           LAST_UPDATE_DATE DESC
                        ) AS RowNum
    FROM
      PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB AS sdist
    WHERE
      EXISTS
        (
          -- Get the set of records that were last updated in the last 7 days.
          -- Correlate to the outer query so it only returns records related to this subset.
          -- This uses a correlated subquery. A JOIN will work, too. Try both, pick the faster one.
          -- Something like this, using the actual natural key columns in the WHERE
          SELECT
            1
          FROM
            PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB AS limit
          WHERE
            --The first two define the date range.
            limit.LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
            AND limit.LAST_UPDATE_DATE <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
            AND
            --And these are the correlations to the outer query.
            limit.EMPLID = sdist.EMPLID
            AND limit.BANK_CD = sdist.BANK_CD
            AND limit.ACCOUNT_NUM = sdist.ACCOUNT_NUM
        )
      AND
      (
        dist.DEPOSIT_TYPE = 'P'
        AND dist.AMOUNT_PCT = 100
      )
      OR dist.PRIORITY = 999
      OR dist.DEPOSIT_TYPE = 'B'
  ) AS dist
    ON
    dist.EMPLID = dd.EMPLID
      AND dist.EFFDT = dd.EFFDT
INNER JOIN
  PS_EMPLOYEES AS emp
    ON
    emp.EMPLID = dist.EMPLID
WHERE
  dist.RowNum <= 2
  AND
  emp.EMPL_STATUS NOT IN ('T', 'R', 'D')
  AND 
  dd.EFF_STATUS = 'A';
```